# Sharing options between selects (using HTML and jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html-select

Looked through many answers, but couldn't find one solving this. I have four (potentially n-number of) `<select>` lists, with an equal number of `<option>` possibilities in each, like this:

```
<label>Pick a:</label>
<select class="colorassign">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>   
<label>Pick b:</label>
<select class="colorassign">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>   
<label>Pick c:</label>
<select class="colorassign">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>   
<label>Pick d:</label>
<select class="colorassign">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">Four</option>
</select>
```

Notice that each available option within the  lists are selected (and each list have the exact same `<option>`s). Now, these should automatically respond to change by not allowing any two lists to have the same selected value. Using jQuery, I want to make it so that when I select for example *Four* in the first list, I want the fourth list to automatically set *One* (the only available free option between the lists) to be set to selected.

Could anyone give a hand with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// get all and dump into a variable to speed things up
var $selects = $("select");

// bind a click even to keep tabs of select values before they're changed
$selects.click(function(){ $(this).attr("current", $(this).val()); });

$selects.change(function(e){
    var $select = $(this);

    // get select that is not the currently changing select with the same
    // value as what the current select changed to. If found, update this other
    // selects value to the changing selects "current" attribute, which is what 
    // it WAS
    $selects.not($select)
        .find("option[value='" + $select.val() + "']:selected")
        .parent().val($select.attr("current"));    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/VVazA/

Comment: That does not appear to work at all; upon changing a value the attribute _current_ is added to the `<select>`, but does not at all affect the `<option>`s within it. As I tried to explain above, I need it to change the _selected_ attribute on the `<option>`s, to only allow each value to be selected once between the lists.

Comment: Thanks! Was a bit confused about the _current_ attribute, but it seems it is a valid attribute in HTML (at least it validated at w3.org). This works great, just what I wanted.

Comment: doesn't work.. Change a to 3, then a back to one. look at the result. both a and c are at one.

Comment: I am having no problems with it... In the demo at jsfiddle it works, even when testing the way you just described it.

Comment: Am having some trouble combining it with the jQuery UI though; should I create a new question, or extend the current one?

Comment: What jQuery UI component are you using?

Comment: Something called SelectMenu (http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html), which styles the dropdown boxes. But while enabled, the "shared options" method you created does not work (presumably because SelectMenu/UI creates some overlay, and does not style directly).

Comment: Exactly, this is not actually using `select` elements, it is rewriting them as `<ul><li>....</ul>` elements and mapping them back to the `select` element

Comment: So, I would need to find another way of styling `<select>`s, that works directly?

Comment: yes, except that you can't style `select` elements very much. You may be able to transform the code provided to interact with that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

How bout this?

```
$("select").each(function() { $(this).attr("current",$(this).val()) });
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).siblings("select").find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']:selected").parent().val($(this).attr("current")).change();
   $(this).attr("current",$(this).val()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YaRF6/4/

Comment: Not working: if you select "two" on the first list, and then select "two" on the second, both have that value.

Comment: My initial idea used `siblings()` as well but it did not work as I would have expected.

Comment: @thomas, you are right, forgot to trigger the change() event for the colliding value at line 3.. It shoulw now work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit less elegant than the other answers, but here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var previous_value;
    var changed_value;
    var selected_object_index;
    $(".colorassign").focus(function() {
        previous_value = $(this).val();
    });
    $(".colorassign").change(function() {
        changed_value = $(this).val();
        selected_object_index = $(".colorassign").index($(this));
        $(".colorassign").each(function(index) {
        if (index != selected_object_index) {
            if ($(this).val() == changed_value) {
                $(this).find("option").removeAttr("selected");
                $(this).val(previous_value);
                $(this).find("option[value="+previous_value+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if this is any good?

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Sorry; this, like matdumsa's answer above, breaks easily. Have to go with hunter's answer as correct.

Comment: No probs, sorry I couldn't help.