# jQuery Selector based on sender

Tags: jquery

I have 4 `select` inputs with the same options. and I am trying to disable any option that has been selected from one of these selects.

```
<select name="homeTeams[]" onchange="check()">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>

<select name="homeTeams[]" onchange="check()">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>


<select name="awayTeams[]" onchange="check()">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>

<select name="awayTeams[]" onchange="check()">
    <option value="1">Team1</option>
    <option value="2">Team2</option>
    <option value="3">Team3</option>
    <option value="4">Team4</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to disable the option that has been selected from one of these selectors. I am using jQuery to do it, but I can't get the value based on the sender.

Ex: if the user has chosen Team1 from Select 1 the `jQuery` code will disable the option Team1 from Select2 and Select3 and Select4.

```
  function check()
  {
      var a = $('select option:selected').val();
      alert(a);
  }
```

it gives me the value of the first select.

any Ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing options between selects (using HTML and jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997139/sharing-options-between-selects-using-html-and-jquery)

Comment: How do you disable an option in select? there isn't such an option.

Comment: @FelixKling. what he wants is impossible as I see it.

Comment: disabled="disabled" property should work?

Comment: @Toni What I want is to add disabled="disabled" on the same option on the other selects

Comment: @Othman you need a "-- select one --" option on each select, otherwise once selected it'll be impossible to change the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution - note the '0' value for "- select -" which allows any value to be deselected:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var vals = {};
    $('select').each(function(i, el) {
        vals[el.value] = 1;
    });
    delete vals[0];

    $('option').prop('disabled', function() {
        return this.value in vals && this.value !== this.parentElement.value;
    });
});​
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Qq33g/

Comment: OK, it's working correctly now AFAICS - I needed to add some logic to ensure that the selected value on each option was still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to Register the event handlers like this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('select')
           .find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
           .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).siblings('select')
           .find('option[value!="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
           .removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

This may work. I haven't tested it.

Comment: One needs to take into account freeing of options as well. Might be easiest to do this with some javascript mvc/mvvm/etc library like knockoutjs.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think that update works... It would free all values not used by this particular sender of the event, but it would free values used by other selects as well.

Comment: @Toni yup, as far as I can see you need to consider the state of _every_ select each time anything changes.